# Unable to delete directory "stage" while building grails war

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

**LOG**

```
[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\BITS Computers\.grails\1.3.7\projects\educoe\stage
    Error executing script War: : Unable to delete directory C:\Users\BITS Computers\.grails\1.3.7\projects\educoe\stage
    : Unable to delete directory C:\Users\BITS Computers\.grails\1.3.7\projects\educoe\stage
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
```

Comment: Some stuck Windows file lock. Try one of these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225802/how-to-determine-which-process-is-holding-a-file-in-windows and kill that process. Or stop your Grails application. If nothing helps, reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... there was no issue... Restarted IDE ....